# Angular 5 - validation not firing on form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 form where I would like to have 2 submit buttons, one to Save Changes, and one to Publish.

Currently I'm just using the (click) handler, but the problem is that my validation isn't firing

The different functions they call are as follows:

```
saveInsight() {

  this.insightService.createInsight(this.insight)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        self.alertService.success("Insight has been created", "", false, false);
      },
      error => {
        self.alertService.validationError(error.error, 'There was a problem creating your insight', false, false);
      });
}

publishInsight() {
  this.insight.is_Active = true;
  this.saveInsight();
}
```

In my HTML I call them like this:

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && saveInsight()" #f="ngForm">

    <input id="heading" heading type="text" required name="heading" [(ngModel)]="insight.heading" #heading="ngModel" type="text" />
    <p *ngIf="f.submitted && !heading.valid" class="text-danger">Title is required</p>

    <button (click)="saveInsight()">Save Changes</button>
    <button (click)="publishInsight()">Publish</button>
</form>
```

I've tried adding type="submit" to the buttons, but validation still doesn't fire.

Comment: Validation fires fine here... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebvk8d?file=app/app.component.ts So could you create a demo that showcases issue? With this approach you need of course to check the validity of the form before actually doing the api request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing seems different from what you intend to do. If I'm right you want to take an action based on the button which is clicked, and only if the form is valid; in this case just simply do this:

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm">

    <input id="heading" heading type="text" required name="heading" [(ngModel)]="insight.heading" #heading="ngModel" type="text" />
    <p *ngIf="f.submitted && !heading.valid" class="text-danger">Title is required</p>

    <button [disabled]="!f.form.valid" (click)="saveInsight()">Save Changes</button>
    <button [disabled]="!f.form.valid" (click)="publishInsight()">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Please notice that I've disregarded what you're doing in the functions and just have focused on the way to enable/disable them based on the validity of the form.

Comment: oh I see, this disables the button if the form isn't valid - I sort of prefer my approach, that if the user clicks submit, THEN the validation fires and shows the appropriate error messages

Comment: In that case you don't even need to check the validation in the template! Just let the button click handler to be called and then check the validation inside that function.